# OPC UA performance evaluation using OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, opc-ua

I am working on OPC UA evaluation project and when I am clicking build project then this error are coming.

Please help

> 12:52:03 **** Build of configuration debug for project OPC UA
>   Performance check **** make MODE=debug all  MSGC:
>   msgtypes/OPC_ActivateSession.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_ActivateSession_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CloseSecureChannel.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CloseSecureChannel_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CloseSession.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CloseSession_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CreateMonitoredItem.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CreateMonitoredItem_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CreateSession.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CreateSession_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CreateSubscription.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_CreateSubscription_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_GetEndpoints.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_GetEndpoints_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_OpenSecureChannel.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_OpenSecureChannel_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_Publish.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_Publish_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_Read.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_Read_Response.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_UATCP_ack.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_UATCP_err.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/OPC_UATCP_hel.msg
>
> MSGC: msgtypes/SOAP.msg
>
> utils/CA.cc utils/xmlParser.cc utils/xmlParser.cc:710:31: warning: ISO
>   C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'
>   [-Wwritable-strings]
>       if (!source) return _CXML("");
>                                 ^ 1 warning generated. 
> msgtypes/OPC_ActivateSession_m.cc In file included from
>   msgtypes/OPC_ActivateSession_m.cc:29:
>   msgtypes/OPC_ActivateSession_m.h:22:10: fatal error:
>   '../OPC_CommonTypes.h' file not found
>   "#include "../OPC_CommonTypes.h""
>   1 error generated.
>  make: *** [Makefile:154: out/clang-debug//msgtypes/OPC_ActivateSession_m.o] Error 1
>
> 12:52:15 Build Finished (took 11s.804ms)

Comment: Could you show `OPC_ActivateSession.msg` and write where do you have `OPC_CommonTypes.h`?

Comment: StackOverflow is a place where people _publicly_ ask a question and someone _publicly_ answers to it. So I cannot remotely help you. I suggest editing your question and adding the aforementioned information.

Comment: Are you maybe using an older project developed for OMNeT 3.x or 4.x with a newer OMNeT 5.x version?